# Хранение документов

Tags: база-данных, mysql, postgresql, sql

Вопрос пока чисто теоретический.

Как хранить в базе данных (MySQL, PostgreSQL) информацию о документах разной структуры,
при этом после запуска в эксплуатацию не менять структуру полей при появлении новых документов?

Например, при разработке есть следующий типовой документ

```
Организация: Рога и Копыта ООО
Дата: 24.10.2011
Валюта: RUB
Сумма: 10000,00
```

Кода запустили в эксплуатацию, появился новый тип документа, который нужно хранить в базе, при этом логически практически не связанный с первым

```
Организация: Ромашка ООО
Дата: 25.10.2011
Наименование  Ед изм   Цена
Товар 1       шт.      5000,00
Товар 2       г.       1000,00
```

А там через месяц еще надо хранить другой документ

```
Дата 31.12.2011
Сумма: 1000000,00
Назначение: Премия под Новый Год
```

То есть нужен своего рода паттерн для универсального хранения документов. Просто XML в поле запихать не подходит.
Данные необходимо будет потом анализировать. То есть во всякие отчеты вставлять с помощью SQL запросов.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, не лучшее решение, но все же:

Таблица под описания видов документов.

```
ТипыДокументов (Код, Наименование, ....)
```

Таблица под конкретные экземпляры документов и их общие атрибуты (номер, дата, комментарий, проведен/не проведен итп...):

```
ЭкземплярыДокументов (Код, ТипДокумента, ... общие поля...)
```

Перечень возможных полей в документах:

```
ПоляДокументов (Код, Наименование, ТипДокумента, ТипДанных)
```

Привязка полей документов:

```
ПоляПоДокументам (Код, ТипДокумента, ПолеДокумента)
```

Значения полей в документах:

```
Значения (Код, ЭкземплярДокумента, ПолеДокумента, Значение)
```

В итоге выйдет что-то вроде Key-Value хранилища.

Получить все поля конкретного документа можно например так:

```
select пд.Наименование, з.Значение 
from Значения з left join ПоляДокументов пд on пд.Код=з.ПолеДокумента
where з.ЭкземплярДокумента = <код_нужного_документа>
```

набросал наспех, но, думаю, идею вы уловили.

Comment: Это медленно работает.

Comment: У вас есть другие варианты?

Comment: > Это медленно работает

У нас работает, не жалуюсь ) Причем дополнительно в этой же таблице ведется история версий значений полей и запрос на выборку более громоздкий. Масштабы: более сотни видов документов, около 900 возможных полей, 1-50 полей в документе, тысячи документов в базе.

Comment: Спасибо за пример их реальной практике

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой подход.

1. Создаётся таблица со всеми колонками, которые могут понадобиться, типа int1, int2, string1, string2, date1...
2. Создаётся таблица типов документов и связанная с ней таблица колонок, содержащая идентификатор типа документа, внешнее имя колонки и имя колонки в общей таблице колонок.
3. Создаётся общая таблица документов, содержащая идентификатор документа и идентификатор типа документа.

После этого можно обращаться к выборке из таблицы документов, которая формируется по таблице типов документов и их колонок, как к подзапросу.

В принципе, можно ещё изучить структуру представлений, в которых отображается структура объектов БД, чтобы можно было управляемо изменять физическую структуру БД.

Comment: Этот способ имеет слабое место: кол-во столбцов в таблице ограничено.

 - Для PgSQL это 250-1600, в зависимости от типа.
 - Для MyISAM - 65 Кб на строку или 4096 столбцов (что раньше кончится, если хранить много длинных строк, то упремся в лимит по объему).
 - Для InnoDB - 1000 столбцов.

Answer (score 1):

Задача сводится к хранению слабо-структурированных данных.

В PostgreSQL стоит обратить внимание на тип данных JSONB
(http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html)

Вот неплохая презентация на эту тему:
http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/talks/RIT-Bartunov-Korotkov-2014.pdf

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Answer (score 0):

Если чисто sql, то таблица:

1. номер записи
2. тип значения
3. значение

Пример:

```
(1, Организация,              Ромашка ООО)
(1, Дата,                     25.10.2011
(1, Товар 1                   5000,00)
(1, Товар 2                   1000,00)
(1, Товар 1 размерность,      шт.)
(1, Товар 2 размерность,      г.)

(2,  Дата,        31.12.2011)
(2,  Сумма,       1000000,00)
(2,  Назначение,  Премия под Новый Год)
```

Дерзайте)

Comment: С условными типами документов 1 и 3
в общем то согласен, однако есть вопрос
в поле ЗНАЧЕНИЕ будет текстовым?


А с документами типа 2 необходимо хранить таблицу
а не просто Тип = Значение

Comment: Необходимо что-то вроде EXCEL
с произвольным числом строк и столбцов
и не обязательно в одной таблице

Comment: поле значение может и вовсе отсутствовать в данной таблице, можно его хранить в зависимости от типа в другой таблице со ссылкой на него, либо некоторые типы данных хранить ссылкой на отдельную таблицу.

Comment: но чесно советую вам отказаться от такой идеи, и таки модифицировать именно структуру таблицы. при необходимости синхронизаций гемора больше, а вот прирост в скорости обработки существенней

Answer (score 0):

Если убрать условие, что в базе таблицы не меняются (а кто такое условие поставил?), то возможным решением будет генерация запросов по метаданным.

Comment: Это связано с тем что программа имеем несколько территориально разнесенных локальных баз (каналы передачи данный нестабильные) которые обмениваются между собой при этом при изменении структуры таблиц в одной из баз необходима синхронизация между остальными. Это останавливает обмен.

Получается что-то типа распределенной базы в 1С 
когда при изменении метаданных необходимо обновить конфигурацию

а в удаленных филиалах специалистов просто нет

Comment: такие вопросы:
в чем необходимость синхронизации структуры? 
если базы полностью синхронизируются, то синхронизации данных плохой канал будет мешать в еще большей степени?

вопросы можно считать риторическими

Comment: Способ хранения данных в БД никак не связан с тем, что требуется обмениваться данными о синхронизации по ненадёжным каналам. Если не предполагается, что пользователь может менять структуру БД, и её изменение происходит только на этапе разработки, то однозначно надо изучать представления метаданных и работать с изменяющейся физической структурой БД.

Comment: DSN, не знаю на чем у тебя разработано клиентское приложение, но попробуй глянуть в сторону сериализации. Общие параметры для всех документов (№, дата, автор ...) пишешь в БД, а специфические реализуешь в виде объекта класса, который сериализуешь и записываешь в БД (blob - поле). Т.е. структура таблицы: id,date_s,author,doc_object. Подобную реализацию я встречал в одном из старых журналов "Компьютеры + Программы"

Comment: Это хорошо, если не надо делать запросы по нестандартным атрибутам документов.

Comment: Согласен. Может все нестандартные атрибуты сделать текстовыми? Тогда имеем три таблицы: главная (№ и т.д.), атрибуты (id, имя), документы (id главная, id атрибута, значение.)

Comment: Нет никакой разницы - запрашивается структура документа выборкой из пользовательской монолитной таблицы или запросом метаданных. В большинстве серверов эта такая же таблица. Посмотрите например в MySQL базу information_schema

Comment: Поиск по всем атрибутам стандартными средствами SQL запросов основное условие

Может я немного ввел вас в заблуждение
Изыскания пока чисто теоретические, но с возможным использованием в дальнейшем
Плохие каналы связи, отсутствие специалистов и синхронизация локальных баз это в будущем

Comment: Совершенно верно заметили что 
Способ хранения данных в БД никак не связан обменом данными и целостностью при передачи по плохим каналам связи - согласен

Изначально изыскания велись в сторону
КАК СТРУКТУРИРОВАНО ХРАНИТЬ РАЗНОТИПНЫЕ ДОКУМЕНТЫ С МИНИМУМОВ ИЗВРАЩЕНИЙ
а в свою очередь типов документов много
от простых писем до бухгалтерских отчетов которые нужно анализировать

Comment: при этом не создавать новую таблицу для каждого нового типа документа

пришлось добавить сюда ...

Может и фетиш
но представите у вас 100 разнотипных документов
которые дано занеси в базу данных и при этом 
что прикажите создать 100 отдельных таблиц

при большом количестве документов 100 таблиц может и оправдано
но если у вас всего 5 документов одного типа то
для 5 документов создавать таблицу отдельную

Comment: "не создавать новую таблицу" - это похоже на фетиш. я совсем не настаиваю на таком решении, но почему это условие ставится как обязательное - решительно не понимаю

Comment: Представляю. Вы решаете реализовать хранение в одной таблице статической структуры и пишете какой-то админский пульт. Это приложение заносит в таблицу строчки с описанием полей, используя операторы DML. Такое же приложение, которое использует разные таблицы будет кидать серверу операторы DDL. Яйца в профиль

Comment: Еще попробуй так: Таблица1 - главная (код,обязательные поля для всех документов), Таблица2 (код и имя параметра (в твоем случае Организация, Товар1 и др.)), Таблица3 (главный код документа, код параметра, значение_строка, значение_число ...). Т.е. для каждого документа записываем в Таблицу3 параметр=необходимый формат значения. А потом все пустые (NULL) поля отсеиваем.  GUI реализовать элементарно.